# firebase-debug.js documentation?

Tags: firebase

I've found the `firebase-debug.js` file that is [used in some example tests](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/test/unit/servicesSpec.js) too, is there a documentation somewhere to know what it provides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `firebase-debug.js` is an unminified version of the compiled Firebase Web client, `firebase.js`. It can be useful in cases when you want to set breakpoints in the code or need to track down the line number of an error / warning to a specific instruction.

Comment: then could you tell me where are methods like `firebaseStub` defined? e.g. https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/test/unit/servicesSpec.js#L11

Comment: [https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/test/unit/servicesSpec.js#L263](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/test/unit/servicesSpec.js#L263)

Comment: It came in really handy tracing down "firebase.js Uncaught Error: ..." messages; firebase-debug.js accompanies these with a nice "FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback." followed by a stack dump :-)

Comment: Does anybody know where the current debug-file is for firebase 3.x? Can only find the minified version on github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-bower